# Give submit button a label that's different from value passed to controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, button, razor

I have this form on my page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateComment", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
       {
           string xid = Model.Id;

           @Html.TextArea("comment", new { @class = "form-control" })

           <input type="submit" value="@xid" name="xid" class="btn btn-primary" />
       }
```

My problem is that the text of the actual button is the value of `Model.Id`. 
My goal is to pass the `xid` to my controller but I want the text on the button to say something else. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` attribute of an `<input type="submit">` element specifies both its label and its posted value.

If you want the label and posted value to differ, then you can use a `<button>` element instead. Put the label (which can include formatting too!) between the `<button>` and `</button>` tags:

```
<button value="@xid" name="xid" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much, will mark as answer asap.